# Stop editing text & images in Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: adobe-acrobat

This may sound like a silly question, but how do you **stop** editing text & images in Acrobat Pro XI?

- Clicking on **Edit Text & Images** again under **Content Editing** does nothing.
- Clicking on the **Edit Text & Images** button in the toolbar does nothing.
- Saving the document does nothing.
- I see nothing under the **Edit** menu that would hint at stopping the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just switch back to either the Hand (press H) or Select (press V) tool.

Answer (score 2):

It finally occurred to me to try pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

click on hand tool or select tool to exit edit mode

[image: acrobat toolbar]